# Reading a file one byte at a time starting from the end to the begining

Tags: python

Hi I am interested in reading a file one byte at a time starting from the end to the beginning.

This is what I have so far:

```
fileName = raw_input()
with open(fileName , "rb") as handler:
    while True:
        piece = handler.read(1)

        if piece =="":
            break
        print piece
```

How can I change this so that I am able to read the file on byte at a tiem from the end to the beginning?

Comment: How big's the file? What are you trying to achieve anyway?

Comment: It's a problem I was given to sole in Java , C# , PHP and Python.I managed to solve it in the first free but I can not solve it in python.The file is a basic text file.

Comment: So what is it specifically about the Python version that you feel makes it different (more difficult?) than what you already wrote in the other languages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, there are two solutions for this issue.

On one hand, you could use tell and seek function"

```
>>> fh = open("e:\\text.txt","rb")
>>> fh.seek(0,2)
>>> length = fh.tell()
>>> for i in range(length, 0, -1):
        fh.seek(i-1,0)
        char = fh.read(1)
        print(char)
```

On the other hand, you could read all content (if file is not too big), and then process it from end to begin:

```
>>> fh = open("e:\\text.txt","rb")
>>> fc = fh.read()
>>> fh.close()
>>> for i in range(len(fc),0,-1):
     print(fc[i-1])
```

Comment: For the second one… why not just `for c in reversed(fc): print(c)`? It's simpler, and much harder to get wrong with off-by-one errors, etc.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. Your way is better, unless we want to process the data one group by one group, rather than one byte by one byte.

Answer (score 2):

What about?

```
with open(fileName , "rb") as handler:
    size = handler.seek(0, 2) #2= SEEK_END
    while size > 0:
        size -= 1
        handler.seek(size)
        b = handler.read(1)
        print b
```